# What is the difference between TypeVar(bound=Hashable) and just Hashable

Tags: python, type-variables

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Hashable, Mapping
from typing import TypeVar, Any

K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)


def func1(data: Iterable[K]) -> Mapping[K, Any]:
    t_dict = {k: 0 for k in data}
    return t_dict


def func2(data: Iterable[Hashable]) -> Mapping[Hashable, Any]:
    t_dict = {k: 0 for k in data}
    return t_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data1 = [[1, 2, 3] * 3]
    func1(data1)
    func2(data1)
```

"""
What is the difference between TypeVar(bound=Hashable) and just Hashable. How it work?
"""

Comment: Please render your code with triple backtick (```) fences and add some context and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Occurrences of the abstract base class `Hashable` (or indeed any class) in the type signature are *independent*: each one can refer to a completely different type:

```
def foo(x: Hashable) -> Hashable:
    return 3
```

This type-checks because no matter what hashable value you pass as an argument, `3` (as an `int`) is a hashable value.

Type variables must be bound to the *same* class in each occurrence.

```
def bar(x: K) -> K:
    return 3
```

This definition does not type-check because an `int` is only a valid return value if an `int` is passed as an argument.

Comment: Which is not to say that the type variable must be bound to the *exact* class of the argument, but I'm not sure explaining why `def foo(x: T, y: T) -> T: return x` allows `foo(3, "bar")` to type-check is in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the func1 TypeVar(K) will treat Hashable and all subtypes from it.
It will work if we passed typed data1.
For instance data1: list[list[int], float] = [[1, 2, 3], 4.0].
And now all are worked!

Comment: Maybe ... I'm LOX

Comment: More importantly, `func1` ensures that the return value has the same type as the argument, not just *some* hashable. `func2` might take a list of `int`s, but returning a `dict` with `float` keys is consistent with its type.